# Multiple junction tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm designing ms sql videocchat database and it's hard for me to design multiple many-to-many relations between two tables.
My project requirements:

- There are *users* and *rooms*
- any *user* can create new *room*
- Each *room* holds a debate
- Each *room* can have *observers* or *members* (participants) of the debate
- Each room has one or more *moderator* (person who opens the room is a moderator by default and then he can nominate other users in the room to be moderators too)
- Each *moderator* has to be a *member* or *observer* (just like all *users* in *room*)
- There is a chat in each room where both *observers* and *members* can write *messages*
- only *members* can do *videostreaming*
- *moderator* can ban any user in the room (kick him out so that if he's on the *banned* list he can't go back to the room)
- *banned* list should contain information about which *moderator* gave a ban for which *user* and for what reason

I've ended up with database below but i feel like there is too much redundancy in my design(information about relation many to many between room and user) but at the same time I don't have an idea to simplify this. [sql diagram picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8WHC.png)

[image]

[edit]

UserStatus is information if user in room is observer or member

isStreaming entity is to be deleted (UserStatus describes it allready)

RoomStatus can be ignored

Answer (score 1):

The only redundant tables IMO are Moderators and Banned.

***Moderator*** is merely an attribute of a user (room user to be specific). You can just have one column, `is_moderator` in `Room_Users` table.

***Banned*** is not required unless you want to use it as a log or there's a requirement to ban user at global level. In your case user will be banned at a room level. You can have columns `banned_by` and `ban_reason` in `Room_Users` which would have values only if room user is banned, else `NULL`.

As a side note: You need to re-think of your naming standards unless what you have used already is part of your organization's standards. Use room_user or RoomUser. This is purely my opinion and you need not follow it blindly.

Also I suggest on using Singular name for your tables. Table name should go with what an individual records indicate. `User` instead of `Users`. This makes more sense when your application code uses a property that holds collection of table records. For example, `public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }` vs `public User User { get; set; }`. Use singular name for SQL tables is not just my opinion but kind of a standard too. You can do further reading on Google.